# PHP failed to open stream: Invalid argument sugarcrm

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I would like to ask for help again on how to fix this error, if this seems like an easy to fix error, i apologize because i have no experience when it comes to phpmyadmin.

> **Failed to open stream:** Invalid argument in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sugarcrm\ModuleInstall\ModuleInstaller.php on line 1701

```
            if(copy( $dest, $rest)) { <== this is line 1701
                if(is_writable($rest))
                    sugar_touch( $rest, filemtime($dest) );
            }
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Have you done a `print_r()` or `var_dump()` on either `$dest` or `$rest`?

Comment: @Rasclatt no i haven't. that showed up on the display log while i was trying to install a module on sugarcrm

Comment: Try doing `var_dump($dest);` and  `var_dump($rest);` and see if they are two valid paths.

Comment: As pointed by Rascalatt, `var_dump()` both `$dest` and `$rest` and see if they show expected paths. Also if you are using Windows system, the backslash in the file path will need escaping.

Comment: ok i just change that and then run the installation again?

Comment: MAke sure that you have given 755 permission to your cache,custom,ajaxFiles folders..